# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'orders.deleted_at' in 'where clause'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

In my table i don't have deleted_at column but the Laravel query always checks if `deleted_at` is `null`, resulting in this error message:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'orders.deleted_at' in 'where clause'

Below is my code

```php
public function load($id) {
    return $this
        ->select(sprintf('%s.*', $this->getTable()))
        ->where(sprintf('%s.%s', $this->getTable(), $this->getKeyName()), '=', $id)
        ->first();
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: side note: if you only want one record use `first()` instead of `get()`

Comment: Please share more information about the issues.

Comment: additional side note: perhaps in the `sprintf` in the `where` you want to use `%s.%s` instead of `%s.id`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to remove the traits `use SoftDeletes;` from your model file.

and then use below code:

```
 return $this->where(sprintf('%s.id', $this->getTable(), $this->getKeyName()), '=', $id)
        ->pluck('id');'
```

Comment: how does `pluck` help in this scenario, when using SoftDeletes?

Comment: you have to remove `SoftDeletes`

Answer (score -1):

As you are using `SoftDeletes`, so it has to save the date and time when the record is deleted.

Simply add this into your `up` function in table migration:

```
$table->softDeletes($column = 'deleted_at', $precision = 0);
```

More about SoftDeletes: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#soft-deleting

Answer (score -2):

Try adding withTrashed() to your chain:

```
public function load($id) {
    return $this
        ->withTrashed()
        ->select(sprintf('%s.*', $this->getTable()))
        ->where(sprintf('%s.id', $this->getTable(), $this->getKeyName()), '=', $id)
        ->first();
}
```

Comment: The database table was not configured for soft deleted models, so the model should not import the soft delete trait. That was the solution years ago, and it remains so now.